# Loading Multiple Modules Lazily in Angular 6

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am trying to create an Angular application that supports multiple dashboards. In my `app-routing.module.ts`, I am trying to lazy load all the components from these different dashboards under their defined path.

My `app-routing.module.ts` file defines routes as follows:

```
// other initialization codes
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule' },
{ path: 'dashboardAlpha1', loadChildren: './dash-alpha1/dash-alpha1.module#DashAlpha1Module' },
{ path: 'dashboardAlpha2', loadChildren: './dash-alpha2/dash-alpha2.module#DashAlpha2Module' }
```

In my `app.module.ts` imports, I am adding these modules as:

```
// other codes
imports: [
// other modules
AppRoutingModule,
DashAlpha1Module,
DashAlpha2Module,
]
```

Now the problem is that when I try to navigate to any routes under `dashboardAlpha1`, it works fine. When I try to navigate to any routes under `dasboardAlpha2`, I get an error:

```
 Component RespondentViewComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module
```

Now, both the dashboards have components with same name and using the same path. For example,

```
/dashboardAlpha1/home
/dashboardAlpha2/home
```

Based on login, I have to redirect to one of the dashboard. Both the modules are setup in the same way.

What am I doing wrongly?

**EDIT 1**

File `dash-alpha1-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "home", component: DashAlpha1HomeComponent },
  { path: "stationView", component: StationViewComponent },
  { path: "profile", component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: "respondentView", component: RespondentViewComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class DashAlpha1RoutingModule { }
```

File `dash-alpha1.module.ts`

```
import { DashAlpha1RoutingModule } from './dash-alpha1-routing.module';
import { DashAlpha1HomeComponent } from './dash-alpha1-home/dash-alpha1-home.component';
import { StationViewComponent } from './station-view/station-view.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { RespondentViewComponent } from './respondent-view/respondent-view.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashAlpha1HomeComponent, StationViewComponent, ProfileComponent, RespondentViewComponent
  ],
 imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashAlpha1RoutingModule
 ],
 exports: [
    DashAlpha1HomeComponent, StationViewComponent, ProfileComponent, RespondentViewComponent
 ]
})
export class DashAlpha1Module { }
```

File `dash-alpha2-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "home", component: DashAlpha2HomeComponent },
  { path: "stationView", component: StationViewComponent },
  { path: "respondentView", component: RespondentViewComponent },
  { path: "profile", component: ProfileComponent }
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashAlpha2RoutingModule { }
```

File `dash-alpha2.module.ts`

```
import { DashAlpha2RoutingModule } from './dash-alpha2-routing.module';
import { DashAlpha2HomeComponent } from './dash-alpha2-home/dash-alpha2-home.component';
import { StationViewComponent } from './station-view/station-view.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { RespondentViewComponent } from './respondent-view/respondent-view.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
DashAlpha2HomeComponent, StationViewComponent, ProfileComponent, RespondentViewComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      CommonModule,
      DashAlpha2RoutingModule
   ],
   exports: [
    DashAlpha2HomeComponent, StationViewComponent, ProfileComponent, RespondentViewComponent
   ]
  })
  export class DashAlpha2Module { }
```

Comment: One component can only be added declarations of exactly one @NgModule()
You cant have RespondentViewComponent in two modules. What you can do is create a shared module with that component, and import the module in those two DashAlpha modules.

Comment: @callback Okay I changed the component names in dash-alpha2 module so that there are no clashes in class names. Now, when I try to add both `DashAlpha1Module` and `DashAlpha2Module` in the `app.module.ts`, there is an undefined error. Specifically, `undefined is not a function`. The modules work when I use only one them. Based on your comment, I thought it would be quicker to just change class names in each files for dash-alpha2 module.

Comment: You should not add those modules to app.module.ts if you are going to lazyload them!

Comment: @callback Thanks so much. Removing the modules from `app.module.ts` imports solved the problem. There are no undefined errors and the pages are loading as expected from their respective module. Finally, changing the class names for components worked but, it was a hack and the better approach will be to use a common, shared module as pointed out by @callback

Comment: Np buddy! Happy to help!